# Different ImageView size in a listView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, imageview

I have a custom listview with ImageView and EditText , my problem is, with different image the size of imageview is different, like in photo.
How can I make sure that all images have the same size?

[Image of listView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th14u.png)

This is my XML code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="150px"
    android:layout_height="150px"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
```

Comment: try android:scaleType="fitCenter"  scaleType

Comment: Simone - If you have solved your own question, please add answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with different aspect ratio images your best approach is to choose a aspect ratio in your layout and center crop your images so they fill the available space.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for better size, create linear layouts for each row containing an **Imageview** and **Edittext**.
You have set `ScaleType` to `fitXY` and that is good. Now use `dp` or `fill_parent` for **Imageview** size.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I have solved this - I have simply remove this `android:layout_weight="0.1"`.